# docker login to quay.io from a Windows Server VM not working

Tags: docker

I am running a Windows Server 2019 VM in virtual box. I managed with quite difficulty to install docker into the server. I am trying to pull a wildly docker image from quay.io. however, when I try to login to quay.io I get the following error

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://quay.io/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I did include the following fields to `C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json` and restarted docker

```json
{
    "registry-mirrors": [],
    "insecure-registries": ["quay.io:5000"],
    "debug": true,
    "experimental": false
}
```

but that didn't work for me

in a previous user post I read that I had to enable "Docker CLI Password" in Docker Desktop, however, since I am using a Windows Server 2019 VM I cannot install docker desktop

I also tried to install the certificate via the browser, but that didn't work aswell, the browser still shows a certificate error.

Comment: You might want to check if date on your VM is set correctly.